# How to reject the transaction after sending for collecting signature's of Counter parties by failed to do digital signature?

Tags: corda

Party A and Party B doing transaction where Party C extra participant. if Party C wants to reject the transaction by fail to do digital signature while collecting signature, it would possible to do that? if then, how counter parties will get the notification about that transaction to reject or accept?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Party C's Signature has to be mandated to do the Tx. you can put his public key in your `Command` at the time of creating the Tx between party A and party B. That's how Party C's signature will become mandatory. You can then send the Tx over to Party C to get his signatures, if all goes well as per your business logic then sign the tx and return `signed transaction`, if not, throw an exception or don't sign the Tx at all.

When you call finality Flow, it checks if all the required signers that were mentioned in the command have signed the tx or not. If not, The Tx is never notarized. I think you can also call `verifyRequiredSignatures` to check if the required signers have signed the Tx or not. at that point you know Party C has not signed your Tx.

Comment: how to push the notifications or message to all counter parties who are all in that transaction, apart from updation of transaction in respective state's vault?

Comment: what notifications you want to push?

Comment: "you have successfully signed the transaction and tx's id" message should from initiator to all counter parties

Comment: I don't think there is any other way than to create flow sessions and send the messages. I'd rather not do it as once the state is finalized, interested parties will automatically get to know about it.